# Node.js readline property doesn't ask for input

Tags: node.js

Node.js readline property doesn't stop for input, instead continues program, causing app to crash. While trying to solve this I found out that apparently node does the whole code simultaneously and doesn't because of that stop for input. I found out ways to run this code but they didn't work for me.

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin, 
 output: process.stdout
});

var token;
var pass;
rl.question('token: ', (tok) => {
  token = tok;
  rl.close();
});

rl.question('pass: ', (pas) => {
  pass = pas;
  rl.close();
});
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking something like below:

```
const readLine = require('readline');
const util = require('util')
const { promisify } = util;

const readline = readLine.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    });

// Prepare readline.question for promisification

readline.question[util.promisify.custom] = (question) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    readline.question(question, resolve);
  });
};


let questionPs =  promisify(readline.question);

 async function askQuestions (questions,readline) {
  
 let answers= [];
 for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
 let tmp = await questionPs(q[i]);
 answers.push(tmp)
 
 }
  console.log(answers);
  readline.close();
}
// Usage example:
let q =  ['token:','pass:']
askQuestions(q,readline)
```